# проблема создания сертификата

Tags: сертификат

Пытаюсь создать сертификат

```
certbot certonly --agree-tos --standalone -d bla.bla.edu --email admin@bla.bla
```

выдает

```
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator standalone, Installer None
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
tls-sni-01 challenge for bla.bla.edu
Waiting for verification...
Cleaning up challenges
Failed authorization procedure. bla.bla.edu (tls-sni-01): urn:acme:error:connection :: The server could not connect to the client to verify the domain :: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for bla.bla.edu    
IMPORTANT NOTES:
     - The following errors were reported by the server:

       Domain: bla.bla.edu
       Type:   connection
       Detail: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for
       bla.bla.edu

       To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
       entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
       contain(s) the right IP address. Additionally, please check that
       your computer has a publicly routable IP address and that no
       firewalls are preventing the server from communicating with the
       client. If you're using the webroot plugin, you should also verify
       that you are serving files from the webroot path you provided.
```

Comment: словами опишите что вы хотели получить и что вместо этого получается. Создайте более информативный заголовок [ask]

Comment: и? по русски же написано, что не может найти А-запись для домена несуществующего

Comment: ну наверное непонятно, что это вообще значит и что за А-запись

Comment: Почитайте про DNS

Comment: @DaemonHK прям-таки по-русски =D